# Could not allocate CursorWindow due to error -12

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application in that I am using SQLite database for storing local data.

In simple query, it worked properly but when I'm using sub-query and joins I'm getting below exception:

> E/CursorWindow(27359): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.example.demo/databases/db_demo.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.

How to resolve this exception?

Comment: post your code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the Error -12 i think cursor leak. try to close it or handle it properly.

```
try {
    // your code
} finally { 
    cursor.close();
}
```

I hope it work. If not post code.

Comment: Thank u..it worked

Comment: If you have `cursor.close()` in the `finally` block, you shouldn't need to run it in the `try` block because it will always get called, correct?